# Calculate Row Percentage Bash One line Command

Tags: bash, percentage

I need to know how to calculate row percentages using a one line bash command. Suppose the content of my file `test.tsv` looks like this:

```
Item Sort   Clicks A    Clicks B
Item 1  100 50
Item 2  60  40
```

I want to know what the percentage for each click sort by item is so it would look like:

```
Item Sort   Clicks A    Clicks B
Item 1  66.70%  33.33%
Item 2  60% 40%
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: `echo "Item Sort Clicks A Clicks B Item 1 66.70% 33.33% Item 2 60% 40%"`

Comment: @JID, man, you forgot to enable interpretation of backslash characters for echo and to embed newlines `:p`

Answer (score 0):

Use awk for this kind of thing, bash doesn't do real/floating-point arithmetic.

Awk script:

```
NR==1 { print }
NR>1  { printf("%s %d %.2f%% %.2f%%\n"
              , $1, $2
              , ($3*100/($3+$4))
              , ($4*100/($3+$4))
              ) }
```

Which means:

- If line number is 1, just print it as-is.
- For other lines, print columns one and two as-is, but calculate the respective percentage for columns 3 and 4.

In one line:

```
awk 'NR==1{print}NR>1{printf("%s %d %.2f%% %.2f%%\n", $1, $2, ($3*100/($3+$4)), ($4*100/($3+$4)))}' test.tsv
```